# How do I create uninitialized pointers that I can pass to FFI functions in a thread-safe manner?

Tags: pointers, rust, ffi

I have some Rust code that passes pointers to a FFI function like this:

```
let mut mu = MaybeUninit::uninit();
let mut p = mu.as_mut_ptr();

let r = unsafe {
    ffi_fn(&mut p)
};
```

This works fine with one thread, but with many threads I think `MaybeUninit::uninit()` will give the same pointer to two threads concurrently, which causes issues.

Comment: Why would you want to pass an uninitialised pointer to a function?

Comment: There may be a lot of ways to add threads to a program. We'll need more information. I don't really see what `MaybeUninit` has to do with whether the pointer is the same for multiple threads, anyway.

Comment: @mcarton for example `sqlite3_open` takes a pointer as its 2nd argument. https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html

Comment: In that case, you could just give it `null`. But like @trentcl, I don't think there is enough information in your question to answer it. In particular, this has nothing to do with threads, and I don't see why it would be a problem to give the same value to this function concurrently.

Comment: If `sqlite3_open` takes a mutable pointer to a mutable pointer to something, then the first pointer (What is held in the `MaybeUninit`) is irrelevant, because as soon as the value under the outermost pointer is replaced, it's different than the one the `MaybeUninit` holds. Just use [`std::ptr::null`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/fn.null.html) or [`std::ptr::null_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/fn.null_mut.html).

Answer (score 3):

As Optimistic Peach and trentcl pointed out in the comments, the correct way of doing this is by retrieving a null-pointer ([playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=48e4e94a7ac7144d15366043d21f3885)):

```
let ptr: *mut i8 = std::ptr::null_mut();
let ptr_to_ptr: *const *mut i8 = &ptr;
```

The same behavior as C applies: even though the pointer itself is `NULL`, a pointer to this is a valid address in memory. It will then be up to the other side of the FFI boundary to change this address to something other than `0x0`, and you'll get that change (since you also have a direct reference to it).